# query display data on one row

Tags: mysql

How can I get the values that are displayd at the rows Total, free, used on one row instead of three rows under each other.

```
SELECT 
h.host as 'Server', 
i.key_,max(x.clock), 
case when i.key_ like '%Total%' then x.value end as 'Total',
case when i.key_ like '%free%' then x.value end as 'free',
case when i.key_ like '%used%' then x.value end as 'used',
x.itemid, 
x.value
FROM `history_uint` as x
left join items as i on x.itemid = i.itemid
left join hosts as h on h.hostid = i.hostid
Where i.key_ LIKE 'vfs.fs.size%'
group by h.host
```

This is the output I receive at this moment 
[Recieved[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZZMH.png)

[Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf3bV.png)

Comment: Sample data would be help full to understand your problem

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. I cannot believe that you think that a person could understand what you want from what you wrote. I can believe you hoped someone might read it and guess what you want. That is no way to communicate. Please edit your post to say what you mean. You have also shown no effort. Please read & act on [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i.key_ in the select is pointless - it will be indeterminate, otherwise I thing you need conditional aggregation perhaps like this.

```
SELECT 
 h.host as 'Server', 
 max(x.clock), 
 sum(case when i.key_ like '%Total%' then x.value else 0 end) as 'Total',
 sum(case when i.key_ like '%free%' then x.value else 0 end) as 'free',
 sum(case when i.key_ like '%used%' then x.value else 0 end) as 'used',
 x.itemid, 
 x.value
 FROM `history_uint` as x
 left join items as i on x.itemid = i.itemid
 left join hosts as h on h.hostid = i.hostid
 Where i.key_ LIKE 'vfs.fs.size%'
 group by h.host
```

Comment: i is an inner join. Just sayin